# Images in a table with GitHub markdown

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I'm having some problems formatting a README on github.

This is the raw README:

```
| Italic             |  Block letters |
:-------------------------:|:-------------------------:
![](outputs/output_Biotouch/18-15_02-02-2018/Identification/ITALIC/ITALIC_movementPoints_cmc.png)  |  ![](outputs/output_Biotouch/18-15_02-02-2018/Identification/BLOCK_LETTERS/BLOCK_LETTERS_movementPoints_cmc.png)
![](outputs/output_Biotouch/18-15_02-02-2018/Verification/ITALIC/ITALIC_movementPoints_notbalanced_roc.png)  |  ![](outputs/output_Biotouch/18-15_02-02-2018/Verification/BLOCK_LETTERS/BLOCK_LETTERS_movementPoints_notbalanced_roc.png)
![](outputs/output_Biotouch/18-15_02-02-2018/Verification/ITALIC/ITALIC_movementPoints_notbalanced_frrVSfpr.png)  |  ![](outputs/output_Biotouch/18-15_02-02-2018/Verification/BLOCK_LETTERS/BLOCK_LETTERS_movementPoints_notbalanced_frrVSfpr.png)
```

It is just a table with relative references to some images.

The referenced images have all the [same dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PEKl.png).

This is what comes out:
[image]

Why are the images contained in the central row smaller?

Comment: Does the pattern repeat for additional alternating rows?

Comment: The pattern seems to repeat independently from the images: https://i.imgur.com/gTHAg7z.png

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you add a link to the GitHub repository so we can take a look?

Comment: This one: https://github.com/LucaMoschella/BiotouchLearner

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The images in the table have all the same dimension.

The "problem" is that to every image a border is added. The border is white on even rows, and it is light gray on odd rows.

The images in the even rows seem to not have a border because the background and the border are both white.

*(thanks to Shawna of the github support team)*

Answer (score 10):

You can use these html tags for this,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <img src="img1.png"  alt="1" width = 360px height = 640px ></td>

    <td><img src="img2.png" alt="2" width = 360px height = 640px></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
      <td><img src="./Scshot/cab_arrived.png" alt="3" width = 360px height = 640px></td>

      <td><img src="./Scshot/trip_end.png" align="right" alt="4" width = 360px height = 640px>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For More Information ,you can see here [Link](https://github.com/anupamhaldkar/RideSharingProject)